# Is it possible to write a "matchmaking" query in Access 2007?

Tags: database, ms-access, match

I am trying to create a database that will essentially act as a matchmaking service. I have two tables with the same categories, `Clients` and `Opportunities`.

The idea is to enter buy-side `Clients` as we acquire them, filling out the applicable descriptive fields (`EBITDA`, `Gross Revenue`, etc).

Then, when a possible `Opportunity` comes along, I enter that info in its respective table (with `EBITDA`, `Gross Revenue`, etc).

The idea is then to run a query that will essentially "match" records from `Clients` with records from `Opportunities`, in a prioritized order, i.e. the items with most matching fields rank at the top.

So I've created the tables (`Clients` and `Opportunities`), a third table `Values` that contains the possible choices for several of the fields, and forms for entering the information into `Opportunities` and `Clients`.

I've entered a test record in both `Opportunities` and `Clients` tables with several matching fields. But my query isn't returning any hits. Per some advice I received, I tried to add in some SQL code to address a possible NULL issue, but Access won't accept the code. Can this query be written? Are the results I'm looking for possible?

My query, designed using the Wizard, looks like this and returns no hits, despite the sample records in each table having matching entries:

```
SELECT Clients.*, Opportunities.*
FROM Clients INNER JOIN Opportunities
ON (Clients.[NAICS Sector Codes]=Opportunities.[NAICS Sector Codes])
AND (Clients.[Business Model]=Opportunities.[Business Model])
AND (Clients.[Gross Revenue]=Opportunities.[Gross Revenue])
AND (Clients.EBITDA=Opportunities.EBITDA)
AND (Clients.[EBITDA Margin (%)]=Opportunities.[EBITDA Margin (%)])
AND (Clients.[Growth-Timeframe in Years]=Opportunities.[Growth-Timeframe in Years])
AND (Clients.[Growth-Revenue]=Opportunities.[Growth-Revenue])
AND (Clients.[Growth-EBITDA (%)]=Opportunities.[Growth-EBITDA (%)])
AND (Clients.[Geographical Operational Location Preference]=Opportunities.[Geographical Operational Location Preference])
AND (Clients.[Debt Load]=Opportunities.[Debt Load])
AND (Clients.[Primary Area of Sales Concentration (Geographic)]=Opportunities.[Primary Area of Sales Concentration (Geographic)])
AND (Clients.[% of total revenue from ≤ top 3 customers]=Opportunities.[% of total revenue from ≤ top 3 customers])
AND (Clients.[% of total revenue from ≤ top 10 customers]=Opportunities.[% of total revenue from ≤ top 10 customers])
AND (Clients.[% of total revenue from ≤ top 20 customers]=Opportunities.[% of total revenue from ≤ top 20 customers])
AND (Clients.[Current Management Post-Transaction Plan]=Opportunities.[Current Management Post-Transaction Plan])
AND (Clients.[Preferred Deal Structure]=Opportunities.[Preferred Deal Structure]) AND (Clients.NAPCS=Opportunities.NAPCS)
AND (Clients.Notes=Opportunities.Notes)
AND (Clients.[ZLD Sector Notes]=Opportunities.[ZLD Sector Notes]);
```

Comment: What are your queries on individual tables? Could you post them, as well as their results?

Comment: "Access won't accept the code" is not a problem description. "I created a test record, but nothing matches" isn't either. Your INNER JOIN means that every single field on both table will have to be a 100% match; even one minor mismatch between them will result in an empty result set. So clearly, if you're getting an empty result set, at least one of the Client columns does not match the corresponding Opportunities column. You can see the test data you have; we can't. Start by commenting out all of the AND conditions except the first, and see if you get results. Then add back each AND 1 by 1.

Comment: until you get to the point you stop getting results, and you'll have identified the problem column.